# Sum TimeSpan by extension method simplification

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I found [here](http://www.extensionmethod.net/5609/csharp/timespan/timespan-sum) this extension method

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the sum of the given timeSpans.
/// </summary>
public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans)
{
    TimeSpan sumTillNowTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;

    foreach (TimeSpan timeSpan in timeSpans)
    {
        sumTillNowTimeSpan += timeSpan;
    }
    return sumTillNowTimeSpan;           
}
```

usage:

```
List<TimeSpan> timeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
TimeSpan sum = timeSpans.Sum();// will be 06:00
```

**Question:**

Is this extension useful or could it be also be solved with one line linq like

```
TimeSpan sum = timeSpans.Sum(); //Linq.Sum() - this doesn't compile
```

I would expect this to compile since `Sum()` does internal `+=` all values - the curious about his is that intellisense of Visual Studio suggests me to use `Sum()` and there is a existing overload but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Did you try running the code? are you getting correct result? If yes, then it is useful. Can you explain the context of usefulness ?

Comment: That isn't a question... If you need it, you must evaluate if it's useful for you.

Comment: Obviously if you want a line that executes timeSpans.Sum() you'll need a method extension

Comment: Its working very well. And what is the question?

Comment: @GaurangDave I've updated the question - maybe it's now more clear to you

Comment: Did you create this method inside a static class? Did you import the namespace of the static class where you are trying to do the sum?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this extension is  working fine - this querstion is about a alternative linq approach

Comment: The SUM method available in LINQ can not be directly used here. Answer below by TheGenaral explains it very well about how you can use LINQ SUM to sum up the TimeStamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the following doesn't compile...

```
List<TimeSpan> timeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
TimeSpan sum = timeSpans.Sum();// will be 06:00
```

An alternative to the extension method supplied would be ...

```
TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeSpans.Sum(t => t.TotalMilliseconds));
```

EDIT: As pointed out by *TheGeneral* better to use the Ticks long property to avoid rounding errors if nanoseconds are a concern...

```
TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.FromTicks(timeSpans.Sum(t => t.Ticks));
```

Although I think I actually prefer kurakura88's answer as it uses TimeSpan's Add method which should be more reliable than any other method you could use to Add TimeSpans

Answer (score 4):

Since `Linq`'s `Sum` is not available for `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>`, another alternative is to use `Aggregate` instead.

```
TimeSpan sum = timespans.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1,t2) => t1.Add(t2));
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Mick's answer, **though I'd use ticks** so you don't lose precision.

If you have *Printable Character OCD* you can put it in your own awesome extension:

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
   public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source)
      => TimeSpan.FromTicks(source.Sum(t => t.Ticks));
}
```

**Usage**

```
List<TimeSpan> timeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
timeSpans.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
TimeSpan sum = timeSpans.Sum();
```